# Can't create a Notify after Patch function, Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, microsoft365

Here is my code:

```
Patch(
Projects;
ShowColumns(
    colGridUpdates;
    "Title";
    "Bereich";
    "F_x00e4_lligkeitsdatum";
    "Ge_x00e4_ndert_x0020_am";
    "Auftraggeber";
    "Organisation";
    "ID"));Notify("Das Raster wurde erfolgreich gespeichert";NotificationType.Success;3000);Clear(colGridUpdates)
```

I have a save button in my solution and want to save all the Grid data. The Patch function is ok and has no problems. But if I want to add a Notify afer I get an error befor the Notify function and after the Patch function: The semicolon is red and it says that I don't need it, but if I delete it I get an other error.
Can someone help?

I deleted the semicolon, but got another error: Operator expected

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to double the ; or use "&" after Patch and Notify.

For example :

```
Patch(
Projects;
ShowColumns(
    colGridUpdates;
    "Title";
    "Bereich";
    "F_x00e4_lligkeitsdatum";
    "Ge_x00e4_ndert_x0020_am";
    "Auftraggeber";
    "Organisation";
    "ID"));;
Notify("Das Raster wurde erfolgreich gespeichert";NotificationType.Success;3000);;
Clear(colGridUpdates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to above answer by @Xela,

Some separators and operators in Power apps formula will change based on application author's language:

[image]

You have to use `;` as separator between parameters of a function and `;;` as separator between two functions.

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Power Apps - Formula separators and chaining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/global#formula-separators-and-chaining-operator)